# Compiling Objective C files with gcc-4.7 on OSX with Apple core libraries such as Foundation.h

Tags: objective-c, macos, gcc

I'm somehow unable to compile Objective C files with GCC 4.7 that include any OSX core libraries such as:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

The resulting error always results in a weird GCC output:

```
gcc -c -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wall -W  -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.4/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I../TerrainFluid -I../TerrainFluid/external -I../TerrainFluid -I. ../TerrainFluid/external/osx_bundle.mm -o osx_bundle.o

In file included from 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:123:0,
                 from ../TerrainFluid/external/osx_bundle.mm:24:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSTask.h:69:24: error: expected unqualified-id before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSTask.h:69:24: error: expected ')' before '^' token
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:159:0,
                 from ../TerrainFluid/external/osx_bundle.mm:24:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:36:15: error: expected unqualified-id before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:36:15: error: expected ')' before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:37:39: error: expected type-specifier before 'NSUserScriptTaskCompletionHandler'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:53:15: error: expected unqualified-id before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:53:15: error: expected ')' before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:54:70: error: expected type-specifier before 'NSUserUnixTaskCompletionHandler'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:68:15: error: expected unqualified-id before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:68:15: error: expected ')' before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:69:82: error: expected type-specifier before 'NSUserAppleScriptTaskCompletionHandler'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:86:15: error: expected unqualified-id before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:86:15: error: expected ')' before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserScriptTask.h:87:72: error: expected type-specifier before 'NSUserAutomatorTaskCompletionHandler'
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:160:0,
                 from ../TerrainFluid/external/osx_bundle.mm:24:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSXPCConnection.h:46:11: error: expected unqualified-id before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSXPCConnection.h:46:11: error: expected ')' before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSXPCConnection.h:46:11: error: expected ';' before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSXPCConnection.h:47:11: error: expected unqualified-id before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSXPCConnection.h:47:11: error: expected ')' before '^' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSXPCConnection.h:47:11: error: expected ';' before '^' token
make: *** [osx_bundle.o] Error 1
```

The way to solve this problem was for me to just use the Apple compiler for the Objective C files and g++ (4.7) for the rest of the code.

```
gcc -> /usr/bin/llvm-gcc
g++ -> /usr/local/bin/g++-4.7
```

I would have used clang for all the code but it doesn't support OpenMP yet and gcc-4.2 doesn't support C++11.

[Here](http://svn.wildfiregames.com/public/ps/trunk/source/lib/sysdep/os/osx/osx_bundle.mm) is the sample file I used (it's the Wildfire Games OSX Resource Bundle loader). I read in a [blog post](http://implbits.com/About/Blog/tabid/78/post/building-with-gcc-4-6-on-osx/Default.aspx) that Apple introduced a GCC blocker to stop compiles with GCC.

Now is there a way to compile the code with a non Apple GCC (such as GCC 4.7)? So far I was able to find no documentation on the matter other than to use the Apple compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The very first error shows the problem.

```
@property (copy) void (^terminationHandler)(NSTask *) NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, NA);
```

this is the [Blocks extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29). Main line GCC does not implement support for blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The term "GCC-Blocker" makes sense now.